# Chrome's not showing data in local storage & no valid storage detectors found error

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

Since I'm cheap and need to find games that I don't need to pay for I've played a few amateur games made to run in the browser, which defaults to chrome.

One of those games has a bug with not cleaning up data leading to save files getting rather bloated, and as a result I've known for awhile that if I had too many saves for that game I could fill up all my paltry localstorage space.

Recently I ran into an issue where I wasn't able to make more then one save in another game which doesn't have the same bloat, making me assume I was nearly out of local storage.  I put cleaning it out on my to do list and promptly forgot about it.

Now I can't open any games.  all of them give me an error stating that "no valid storage detectors found"

I've done the standard fixes:

1. Allowed third party cookies and explicitly put the games file based url for the games in my third party cookies allowed section
2. disabled my add blocker entirely

None of this helps.  However I've seen indicators that this error can happen when local storage is full, and considering everything was working not to long ago before I ran out of space with a game I'm inclined to think this is an issue with my local storage being full.

Okay so I open up dev tools, go to application tab, and look at my local storage, I see nothing except for things associated with sites I currently have opened in tabs.  I know there should be more in local storage, such as all my saved games, but I can't see it.  and since I can't see it I can't delete it to clear up space to allow me to open a game.

So how can I get chrome to allow me to play anything?  Ideally without having to completely dump my local storage, after all I do have saved games in there I'd prefer not to loose.  Ideally I'd like to selectively clear out stuff associated with sites/games I'm not using any more to clear up enough that I can re-open the space hog game and then more selectively prune it's saves.

edit: it seems I can open in incognito mode.  which is of limited use since I can't use local storage for saves that way.